# What does @Transactional do?

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-jdbc

I know this is probably  a duplicate and, ironically, before I started reading here and there about it, I **thought** I knew what it was  for (**needless to say** but I'll still say it, please correct me where I am wrong):

It relieves the programmer of having to use `transaction.begin()` and `commit()`.
If you have a method that calls two DAO methods which normally would each have a `transaction.begin` and `transaction.commit` encompassing the real operations and call them it would result in two transactions ( and there might be rollback issues if the previous DAO method was supposed to be rolled-back too).

But if you use `@transactional` on your method then all those DAO calls will be wrapped in a single `begin()`- `commit()` cycle. Of course, in case you use `@Transactional`  the DAOs must not use the `begin()` and `commit()` methods I think.

Comment: One thing want to add is that if you add some code like commit or begin programmaticlly in your method, it will work. The transactional only changes your database connection to not auto commit.

Comment: It is exactly like you say. Good that you catched it well!

Answer (score 12):

You can handle your `Transactions` in two ways: `Programmatically` and `Declarative`.

When you're using `transaction.begin` and `transaction.commit` and ..., you are hanling your `Transactions` programmatically. This way you have more control on your `Transaction` boundaries but you will end up with lots of similar codes (`Cross Cutting Concerns`) scattered all over your project.

But in `Declarative` way, the codes that handle the `Transactions` are separated from your businesses logic and will not be scattered all over your project. It's one of the main concepts of `Aspect Oriented Programming`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you this link that explain everything on Spring Transaction.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html

You should see also the same attribute about Transactional (propagation, rollbackFor, etc), transaction behavior could change if you use those attributes.